# Debugging Chromecast Receiver App (device doesn't support the platform API)

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have a receiver app (stock version from cast-ios-sample) that is correctly getting downloaded from my whitelisted URI, according to the debug panel on port 9222.  However, the console spits out these lines shortly thereafter from google's hosted cast_receiver.js (referenced in the receiver.html file)

```
[  0.162s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined
[  0.172s] [cast.receiver.ChannelOverWebSocket] Dispatch ERROR event to ws://localhost:8008/system/control
[  0.177s] [cast.receiver.Channel] Dispatch ERROR event to ws://localhost:8008/system/control
[  0.182s] [cast.receiver.Platform] Platform channel has an error: ws://localhost:8008/system/control
```

Then after a series of these errors (presumably on a retry loop):

```
[  8.335s] [cast.receiver.Platform] This device doesn't support the platform API.
```

If I try to manually establish a WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:8008/system/control I simply get an undefined response.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that in the receiver.html example, the Receiver needs your AppID as well.  I didn't see this in any of the instructions, so I'm posting the answer here in the event that it helps someone.

```
cast.receiver.Receiver(activityName...)
```

Apparently, activityName is actually the AppID and by placing my AppID (instead of naming my application, as I mistakenly thought), it now works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but using the App ID doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: To clarify, I never actually got rid of the error messages, but everything seems to work.  I think I'm missing something related to what's supposed to happen over the control channel (/system/control).  I'm hoping someone else can provide some insight.